# Does WordPress count as a means to learn web development?

Tags: theme-development

I'm learning to make themes in WordPress, basically with CSS only. I don't feel like I'm learning actual web development (front end). I don't see how I can incorporate JS into themes, because it seems that WordPress does all the stuff for you (such as the drop-down navigation menus).

I know this is a badly written question. Basically, can WordPress be used as a means to learn overall front end development, or should I try it some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

WordPress is inherently web content management system. Whatever you do with it *is* web development since end result is, well, a web site.

However not all of WordPress is web development. Not all of web development is something that you typically do in WordPress.

As you grasped WP is strong at back–end and contains immense amount of functionality, as well as means to produce a lot of markup server-side. This is *good* since it saves you from all that work.

But the other side of the coin is that WP is kind of set in its ways. It is a legacy framework and “newer” (or even years old really) techniques (such as dedicated template languages, JS frameworks, and so on) are often under–explored in it.

In a nutshell starting with WordPress development *does* expose you to considerable amount of generic web development concepts (depending on what exactly you do with it), but it won't be exhaustive and at some point you will have to look beyond WP to make further progress.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view it will make  you very lazy. This is because lot of plugin and themes available for free, that can be used in any business environment. That is the reason about 25% of the websites are running in wordpress

Comment: Yeah exactly. I don't know how else I can practice such.

Comment: @Rockett if know Basic HTML,CSS and very little amount of PHP skills, you can survive in the WordPress world.

Comment: The tools don't make one lazy. Laziness makes one lazy. There are plenty of WordPress people around busy out of their minds. :)

Comment: yes there are plenty of wordpress developer, but am sure most of them learned the css in other platform not in Wordpress.